# Error running gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms throws this error as of the April 16th, 2015 release:

> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app) Invalid choice: 'setup-managed-vms'.

Answer (score 1):

This command has been removed because the base runtime images are now available publicly on the Google Container Registry.

They're available under:
    gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat
    gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat
    gcr.io/google_appengine/go-compat

These can be pulled with a standard "docker pull "

If you replace the google/appengine-* with these image names in the FROM line of your Dockerfile, docker will automatically pull these during builds and deploys.

Comment: As this is not yet obvious in the gcloud documentation and you might be involved with that team. Would it be possible to update the google documentation before such a  non-backward compatible change?

Comment: The docs are updated now: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/getting-started